# Create Index on JSON array object field in Postgres 12

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-12

I have a simple table of **events**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    events_info jsonb,
    createdate timestamp,
    updatedate timestamp,
    CONSTRAINT events_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

**events_info** looks like

```
[
  {
    "id": "test_id",
    "type": "INTERNAL", // but might be EXTERNAL too
    "title": "LOGIN_EVENT",
    "message": "Success login",
    "createDate": "2022-07-07T11:56:52",
  }
]
```

My idea is to create an index for field type in the array of events_info. 
 I tried 
`CREATE INDEX event_info_type_idx ON events USING GIN (jsonb_values_of_key(events_info, 'type') gin_trgm_ops)`
 But got error `jsonb_values_of_key function does not exist` 
 How can I do this correctly?

Comment: If you only have two values for "type" any index will be worthless unless one value is a LOT more common than the other.

Comment: @RichardHuxton it will extend in future

Comment: If you want to use a function named jsonb_values_of_key, you will have to create one first.